# Prevent pull of a branch using a hook

Tags: mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

There is a repository which must be protected from accepting a specific set of named branches coming from other repositories. How can this be accomplished using hooks?

It seems possible by using `pretxnchangegroup` hook, but:

(1) how to determine incoming branch name, and

(2) how to actually abort the operation? Is it possible to abort it before data is transmitted over network to the repository, i.e. only information about what is incoming is sent, but not the files?